# Factorializing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I made a factorial program in javascript, or at least I thought I did. When I don't make it a function it works, but when I do it doesn't, where am I going wrong?

```
function factorialize(num) {
    var text = 1;
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
      text *= i;
}}

factorialize(5)
```

This above doesn't work, I also don't get any error message when I should be getting 120.

```
num = 5
var text = 1;
var i;
x = num;
for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
    text *= i;
}
```

But this outputs 120, so where am I going wrong in my initial code?

Comment: Both work fine, you just need to make sure to return the value or log the result

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement inside the `function`.

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
>   be returned to the function caller.

```js
function factorialize(num) {
    var text = 1;
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
      text *= i;
    }
    return text;
}

console.log(factorialize(5));
```